# example of a not totally bounded metric space with a non locally-compact completion

Tags: metric-spaces

Can someone provide me with an example as such?
A metric space which is not totally bounded with a non locally-compact completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the closed unit ball, but equipped with the metric 
$$d(p,q) = 
\begin{cases}
 |p| + |q| & \text{if $p$, $q$ are not on the same ray based at the origin} \\
 | \, |p| - |q| \, | & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This is a complete metric space. You can think of this as the "metric tree" obtained from the disjoint union of all the oriented segments $[0,p]$, $p \in S^1$, by identifying the initial points of these segments.

$B$ is not totally bounded, because for any point $p \in S^1 \subset B$, any set of diameter $<2$ containing $p$ misses all of the other points in $S^1$. It therefore takes uncountably many balls of radius $< 1$ to cover $B$.

Also, $B$ is not locally compact, because for any $r > 0$ we can find a sequence with no convergent subsequence staying within the radius $r$ ball of the origin: simply pick a sequence of points at distance $r/2$ from the origin all lying on different rays based at the origin. The distance between any two points on this sequence equals $r$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a name formthe interesting metric you pointed out?

Comment: These metric trees are quite common in geometric group theory, and they fall under a larger class of metric spaces called "real trees" or "$\mathbb{R}$-trees" for short.